# Lapply over data table and variable name

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I am trying to convert several variables in several data tables (one variable per data table) from a number to a factor. Here is the code I have so far (not working):

```
DT = data.table(x=c(1,2,3,4), y = c(8,9,10,11), n = c(1,0,1,0))
DT
   x  y n
1: 1  8 a
2: 2  9 a
3: 3 10 b
4: 4 11 b

var_list = list("x","y")

lapply(var_list, function(i) {
  name1 = paste("factor", i, sep="_")
  DT[, num := seq_len(.N), by = "n"]
  dataname = paste("DT",i,sep="_")
  assign(dataname, data.frame(subset(DT,num==1)),pos = .GlobalEnv)
  dataname = data.table(dataname)
  dataname[, name1 := as.factor(get(i)), with = FALSE]
})
```

> Error in get(i) : object 'x' not found

What am I missing?

Comment: `dataname` is a string, so `data.table(dataname)` is just a data.table with a string as its only data point (observation/row and variable/column).

Comment: Your code seems very obscure to me. Can you show the desired output? It seems to me that all you need is just `var_list = c("x","y") ; DT[, (var_list) := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols = var_list]`

Comment: Okay @Frank gave me what I needed. Thanks! I will post the solution below.

Comment: @gannawag Glad you found a workaround, but you should know that, as David said, there is probably a more direct way to achieve your objective, and `assign` is a symptom of code that will create trouble for you later. Having a look through the data.table vignettes might be a good way to start learning better alternatives: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: @Frank thanks, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
lapply(var_list, function(i) {
  name1 = paste("factor", i, sep="_")
  DT[, num := seq_len(.N), by = "n"]
  dataname = paste("DT",i,sep="_")
```

I was trying to convert dataname to a data.table in a separate line, but it was converting to a 1x1 data.table. Instead, convert to data.table in the assign line:

```
  assign(dataname, data.table(subset(DT,num==1)),pos = .GlobalEnv)
```

And then refer to the dataname data.table using the get() function outside the []

```
  get(dataname)[, (name1) := as.factor(get(i))]
})
```